# Typescript foreach on form elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, react-typescript

I wrote a code for foreach on form elements in javascript to give values.

```
const onSubmitForm = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let customerName: string = "";
    Object.entries(event.target.elements).forEach(([name, input]) => {
        if (name === "name") {
            customerName = input.value;
        }
    });
};
```

I want to convert it to typescript. But I've an error on line 3:

> Object is of type 'unknown'.
>
> > var input: unknown

How to fix this?

Comment: Is your event typed already? Also, what is target.elements?

Comment: where did you get customerName? is this new var?

Comment: Iteration is Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => { });

Comment: I updated the codes

Comment: Yes its a let @captain-yossarian

Comment: I would rather try this: `for(element of event.target.elements)if(element.name==="name")customerName=element.value;`

Comment: don't work for me in typescript. @tevemadar tsc said: Cannot find name 'element'.

Comment: sorry, forgot the `let`: `for(let element of event.target.elements)if(element.name==="name")customerName=element.value;`

Comment: You don't need a loop to find a key in an object.  `const customerName = event?.target?.elements?.name?.value || ""`